# How do I configure Textmate2 to turn off Soft Wrap by default for all files?

Tags: textmate2

I put a .tm_properties file in my home folder and also at the top of my source tree with the following in it, none of the versions had any effect.

```
softWrap = false
softWrap = :false
softWrap=false
```

Also with no effect, I put the line below section headers such as:

```
[ source ]
[ text ]
[ "*.*" ]
```

Would love to know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the following entry below and it work just fine. Try removing other file type specific configuration to ensure its not being overridden.

```
softWrap         = false
```

Also do check the "global" defaults under

```
TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/Default.tmProperties
```

If you haven't already seen https://gist.github.com/1478685, do check it out. The tm_properties in your most immediate folder should take priority. So try and remove other setting and just test it with this one.

Alternatively, remove all other tm_properties and just leave the "global" one and test it out.

Finally do check out this [discussion](http://old.nabble.com/TextMate-2-%288930%29---Line-wrap-turns-off-while-editing-scrolling,-some-settings-not-preserved-between-TM2-launches-td32973634.html) and the version of TM2 you are using. There have been certain fixes to softwarp, and it could just be a bug that you are facing.

**EDIT**

Also just FYI, I found this item in the latest release notes of TM2.(2012-02-18)

- Cached .tm_properties files are now observed via kevent so changes invalidate the cache immediately (previously it could take up to 30 seconds before the updated file was read). On file systems without kevent support you need to relaunch TextMate to flush the cache.

Comment: Even with `softWrap = false` source comments are still wrapping in the latest build. There may be a better way, but `wrapColumn = -1` prevents everything from wrapping.

Comment: Additionally, if the soft-wrap of inline comments is annoying you: edit the Source bundle, untick 'Enable this item' for the Style options in Settings that influence wrapping.

Comment: Textmate is wrapping my comments in coffeescript and wrapColumn = -1 is not working properly.  It is making each character of a comment appear on its own seperate line... Is there anyway other way disable all wrapping?